# How to increase RAM for embedded-kafka?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, jvm, embedded-kafka

I use [embedded-kafka](https://github.com/embeddedkafka/embedded-kafka) and I have some problems of stable work of it, reflected in:
`Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:6001) could not be established. Broker may not be available.` and timeouts.

I think that increase of memory can help, but I can't find any property for that. I tried to search code for `memory` or `RAM` words, but no luck. Is it possible to increase RAM for embedded-kafka?

Comment: It's embedded in your own code, it should not fork another process... You could also try using test containers, which do have external processes

Answer (score 0):

There may be other issues also for this error, check the port and server properties.
I think you should increase the heap size of java process. which starts the embedded kafka.

Comment: The embedded kafka starts as a new process with `-Xmx1G` and the question is how to change it from the Java API of tests or from maven pom.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question. Take a look here: [_How do I write a good answer?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)